# Regex to find out if the sequence has any special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regex to find out the given word sequence has any special characters.

For example.

In this input string

```
    "test?test";
```

I would like to find out the words got

```
    "test(any special char(s) including space)test"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `[^A-Za-z0-9]`, which will match anything that is not alphanumeric, but of course it depends on what you consider a "special character." If underscore is not special `[\W]` can be a shortcut for anything that is not a word (`A-Za-z0-9_`) character.

Comment: Just a tiny comment: `[\W]` is the same as `\W`.

Comment: Yes, very true. I had `[^\w]` and then switched it at the last minute and forgot to remove the char class brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a regex here. If you want to test for alphanumeric characters, you car use LINQ, for example (or just iterate over the letters):

```
string input = "test test";
bool valid = input.All(Char.IsLetterOrDigit);
```

`Char.IsLetterOrDigit` checks for all Unicode alphanumeric characters. If you only want the English ones, you can write:

```
public static bool IsEnglishAlphanumeric(char c)
{
    return ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z'))
        || ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z'))
        || ((c >= '0') && (c <= '9'));
}
```

and use it similarly:

```
bool valid = input.All(IsEnglishAlphanumeric);
```